# how to write insert query for table that contains reference column to another table in play-slick with scala?

Tags: scala, slick-3.0, playframework-2.5

I am using slick 3.1, Play framework 2.5 and scala 2.11. My application have 'User' table with reference column 'addressId' which refers to 'id' column of 'Address' table. I am not able to insert data in these both tables. Here is code for this

This is the UserForm:

```
val registerForm: Form[RegisterForm] = Form {
mapping(
  "id" -> optional(number),
  "firstname" -> nonEmptyText.verifying("letters only", name => name.isEmpty || name.matches("[A-z\\s]+")),
  "lastname" -> nonEmptyText.verifying("letters only", name => name.isEmpty || name.matches("[A-z\\s]+")),
  "email" -> text.verifying(nonEmpty),
  "password" -> text.verifying(nonEmpty),
  "address" -> mapping(
      "id" -> optional(number),
      "city" -> nonEmptyText.verifying("letters only", name => name.isEmpty || name.matches("[A-z\\s]+")),
      "state" -> text,
      "country" -> text,
      "pin" -> number
      )(AddressForm.apply)(AddressForm.unapply)
  )(RegisterForm.apply)(RegisterForm.unapply)
 }
```

These are two model classes:

```
case class Address(id: Option[Int], city: String, state: String, country: String, pin: Int)
case class User(id: Option[Int], firstname: String, lastname: String, email: String, password: String, addressId: Option[Int])
```

Here is both classes mapped to corresponding database tables with tables query:

```
private class UserDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "user") {

def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

def firstname = column[String]("firstname")

def lastname = column[String]("lastname")

def email = column[String]("email")

def password = column[String]("password")

def addressId = column[Option[Int]]("address_id")

override def * = (id, firstname, lastname, email, password, addressId) <> ((User.apply _).tupled, User.unapply)

def address_fk= foreignKey("fk_user_address", addressId, addressTable)(_.id)

 }

private class AddressDB(tag: Tag) extends Table[Address](tag, "address") {

def id = column[Option[Int]]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)

def city = column[String]("city")

def state = column[String]("state")

def country = column[String]("country")

def pin = column[Int]("pin")

override def * = (id, city, state, country, pin) <> ((Address.apply _).tupled, Address.unapply)

}


private val userTable = TableQuery[UserDB]

private val addressTable = TableQuery[AddressDB]
```

Please, tell how can i insert data to both the related tables with one query using slick.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use id returning insert for address and an insert to usertable in single transaction, example:

```
val query = for {
  adressId <- addressTable returning addressTable.map(_.id) += Address(....)
  userTable += User(..., Some(adressId), ....)
} yield ()

db.run(query.transactionally)
```

edit: Query above not returning anything, if you need created User, use:

```
val query = for {
  adressId <- addressTable returning addressTable.map(_.id) += Address(....)
  user <- userTable returning userTable += User(..., Some(adressId), ....)
} yield user

db.run(query.transactionally)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @HüseyinZengin, its working and solved my problem.

Comment: This query is returning Unit. what if i want it to return Future[User] ?

Comment: Thank you very much @HüseyinZengin.

Comment: you are welcome, please mark answer as correct, so others can get help

Comment: Sorry buddy, not enough reputation to vote or mark as useful.

Comment: But while using this query foreign key constraint in table is useless. its also working without any reference between two tables. Then what is benefit of foreign key?

Comment: @Govardhan never mind, First: It is working without foreign key because with out foreign key it is still a valid insert, Second: With foreign key you can not insert some random `Long` to that file and also you can select what should happen when records changed, you can see and learn more from: http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/schemas.html#constraints

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thanks again @HüseyinZengin.